# Troubles with .pid files and nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, arch-linux

I am running ArchLinux and nginx, and cannot stop nginx without using a `kill -9` on the actual PID files.

I'd instead like to use `/etc/rc.d/nginx stop` and have the nginx script look in the .pid file for nginx, but the file isn't there. I `touch`ed it, but that didn't help either.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Thanks so much.

**EDIT:** [This](http://cl.ly/1cNM) is what I see when I type `/etc/rc.d/nginx restart`

So something is going wrong here…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any problem doing this, if you start nginx with `/etc/rc.d/nginx start`. The rc script does actually use the pid located in `/var/run/nginx.pid` to quit the nginx daemon.

If that file does not exist, touching alone wouldn't help you much more. Instead you have to write the PID to that file too. But that shouldn't be neccessary in the first place.